# Jenkins Port 8080 to another alternative Port

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to install Jenkins on my pc, but it support 8080 port which is already used by Xammp server, Can Anybody tell me what alternative port I can use and it will worked?

I had already tried 8081,8443 but next java step it gives warning.

Answer (score 0):

There are 65,535 possible port numbers. It could be your firewall blocking the ports. Apps will often use more than one port. One for inbound and one for outbound etc.